# Why synchronize on a static lock member rather than on a class?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

```
class Bob {
  private static final Object locke = new Object();
  private static volatile int value;

  public static void fun(){
     synchronized(locke){
       value++;
     }
  }      
}
```

How is this different from synchronizing on the class, i.e. `synchronized(Bob.class){...}`

Comment: Unrelated note: for this specific use an `AtomicInteger` is the simpler solution ;-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Some *other* code can break yours by doing a `synchronized(Bob.class)`. If they do, your code suddenly contests with *their* code for the lock, possibly breaking your code.

That danger is removed if the `lock` object is not accessible from outside the object that needs it.

Comment: by 'break' you mean deadlock, right? Not that it produces some crazy undefined behavior, like in C++ land. If the thread A locks on the `Bob` class then thread B wont be able to use `fun()`, thats it?

Comment: @BinaryBob It could deadlock or some unrelated code could simply keep the lock for a long time, preventing your class from making progress i.e. causing a [liveness issue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/liveness.html).

Comment: Deadlocks are one big problem, if you have code that depends on `notify()` (which is always risky), then a stray `Bob.class.wait()` call can break that even worse.

Comment: @BinaryBob because notify() only notifies one thread and there's no guarantee that it would be yours.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example with `notify()` e.g. by updating the `Bob` class ?